# Code in Application_Quit() not Running (Outlook)

Tags: vba, email, outlook, outlook-2010

I've added some VBA code to my outlook application to run some clean-up when I close the program.  Specifically, I delete any notification emails automatically generated by my test environment at work.

Then I try to empty my junk folder, mark emails in a specific folder as read, and then permanently delete all the items from my "Deleted Items" folder.  Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Application_Quit()

    On Error Resume Next

    Call delete_LV_emails
    Call mark_JIRA_read
    Call empty_junk
    Call empty_deleted

End Sub
```

The subs that I am calling are in a module named "Cleanup", and I know they all work when I run them on their own.  However, only the "delete_LV_emails" sub gets called.  That is, when I close/re-open outlook.  The only thing that has occurred is that the automatically generated emails are moved to the "Deleted Items" folder.  I can't figure out why only one of the subs is being called.

If it matters, the code for each of the subs is below:

```
Sub delete_LV_emails()

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim olItem As Object
    Dim arrKeys(0 To 1) As String

    Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")                                
    Set olFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)                

    arrKeys(0) = "LabVIEW Error"                                                   
    arrKeys(1) = "Test Complete"

    iItemCount = olFolder.Items.Count
    sDate = Split(Str(Now), " ")(0)

    For iItemInd = iItemCount To 1 Step -1
        Set olItem = olFolder.Items(iItemInd)

        If Not Split(Str(olItem.CreationTime), " ")(0) = sDate Then GoTo NEXTITEM

    iKeyInd = 0

    While Not iKeyInd > 1
        If InStr(olItem.Subject, arrKeys(iKeyInd)) Then olItem.Delete

        iKeyInd = iKeyInd + 1
    Wend

NEXTITEM:
    Next

    Set olNS = Nothing
    Set olFolder = Nothing
    Set olItem = Nothing

End Sub

Sub empty_deleted()

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim olItem As Object

    Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems)

    iItemCount = olFolder.Items.Count

    For iItemInd = iItemCount To 1 Step -1
        Set olItem = olFolder.Items(iItemInd)
        olItem.Delete
    Next

    Set olNS = Nothing
    Set olFolder = Nothing
    Set olItem = Nothing

End Sub

Sub empty_junk()

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim olItem As Object

    Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderJunk)

    iItemCount = olFolder.Items.Count

    For iItemInd = iItemCount To 1 Step -1
        Set olItem = olFolder.Items(iItemInd)
        olItem.Delete
    Next

    Set olNS = Nothing
    Set olFolder = Nothing
    Set olItem = Nothing

End Sub

Sub mark_JIRA_read()

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim olItem As Object

    Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Jira")

    iItemCount = olFolder.Items.Count

    For iItemInd = iItemCount To 1 Step -1
        Set olItem = olFolder.Items(iItemInd)
        If olItem.UnRead Then olItem.UnRead = False
    Next

    Set olNS = Nothing
    Set olFolder = Nothing
    Set olItem = Nothing

End Sub
```

I realize that this is an extremely long-winded question, but if anyone has any insight I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Remove On Error Resume Next from your code then run it again and let me know

Comment: @Om3r Yep... that worked.  So then the question becomes: what is "On Error Resume Next" doing that is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove **`On Error Resume Next`** from your code then run it again

`On Error Resume Next` you are basically instructing VBA to essentially ignore the error and resume execution on the next line of code.

It is very important to remember that `On Error Resume Next` does not in any way "fix" the error. It simply instructs VBA to continue as if no error occurred.

See more info on 
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ErrorHandling.htm

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  I'm still a bit confused, though.  If I remove the "On Error Resume Next" statement, and I don't receive an error message from Outlook, then isn't "On Error Resume Next" moot, as there is no error in the first place?

Comment: Yes you are confusing the the code, you want to know if there is an error, then fix it

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, having the statement in the code causes problems because I don't also have code that handles an error case, even though an error never actually occurs (Please forgive my uncertainty).

Comment: so I'm not sure why it worked the first time, but subsequent tries show that it still doesn't work properly.

Comment: @detroitwilly Have you remove it from all the codes? - also why not make them all one sub?

Comment: I did remove all instances of "On Error Resume Next".  The main reason I'm calling subs is that I developed the subs in a separate module for testing purposes.  Rather than copying/pasting I just called the subs.  That being said, I just copied/pasted all the different code into the Application_Quit() sub, and nothing works with in that case (Although if I open the VBA editor and run the macro by pressing F5, it all works).

Comment: @detroitwilly Here another thought, call each sub from the other sub- example call only delete_LV_emails from Application_Quit then the next one mark_JIRA_read from delete_LV_emails and so on

Comment: Okay, now it's working again.  I'm not sure why it sometimes works and doesn't at other times.  I am going to mark this as the answer right now, since it seems to have solved it.  If it starts misbehaving again, I will try calling one sub from the other, as you've suggested.  Thanks very much for all your help!

Comment: Came back to this with fresh eyes just now, and I think my problems are all user error.  Believe it or not, I think i was just re-opening outlook too quickly (my inbox is a bit cluttered at the moment, so it takes some time to loop through it all).  If I wait a couple seconds before launching again, it all works well.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

The latest versions of Outlook do not call the Quit event handler. They do not pass Go and do not collect $200 - they just quit.

You can watch the `Explorer.Close` and `Inspector.Close` events - if there is only one Explorer or Inspector left (as reported by `Application.Explorers.Count` and `Application.Inspectors.Count`), Outlook is closing.

Comment: Good to know, so does that mean that I would have to create another Explorer/Inspector and then release it at the end of my code?